# Crear rutas para usuarios autenticados y no en rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quisiera crear dos rutas `root`, una para los usuarios autenticados y otra para los que no lo están; para esto utilizo **devise**, probé con el siguiente código pero me da error.

**Error**

> Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' You may have defined two
>   routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be
>   overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.
>   For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources`
>   as explained here:
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

**routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  authenticated :user do
    root 'main#home'
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root 'main#unregistered'
  end
end
```

**main_controller**

```rb
class MainController < ApplicationController
 def home
 end

 def unregistered
 end
end
```

Comment: Hola @denethor. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta mostrando el texto del error?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es porque ambos root que definiste, al no especificar un alias, quedan con el mismo. Prueba a poner:

```
authenticated :user do
    root 'main#home', as: :authenticated_root
end

unauthenticated :user do
    root 'main#unregistered', as: :unauthenticated_root
end
```